# Redirect only POST to nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm currently running into an issue where I want to only redirect POSTs to a specific path within Nginx ingress. This POST redirect should only be for `/log` but not catch `/login`. If I hit `/log` I should not be redirected. This is what I currently have for our ingress. I am considering using CORS but it doesn't seem to work in my testing..

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: client-log-forwarder-ingress
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.service }}
    app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: frontend
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: {{ .Values.partOf | default .Values.service }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {{ .Values.ingress.ingressClass }}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: 60s
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: 60s
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: 60s
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: {{ .Values.logging.sumoRoute | quote }}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "POST"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
spec:
  # ingressClassName: {{ .Values.ingress.ingressClass }}
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.ingress.hostname | quote }}
    secretName: {{ .Values.ingress.ssl | quote }}
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingress.hostname  }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /log$
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sumo-logging-endpoint-service
            port:
              number: 443
{{ end }}
```

Comment: perhaps ,change the `pathType` to `Exact`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `pathType` to `Exact`. Look at [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types).

> `Exact`: Matches the URL path exactly and with case sensitivity.

In this case you also need to remove `$` from our path, as `pathType: Exact` will also try to match it as literal $.

Comment: Thank you, my post actually didn't cover the entirety of my requirements.. I need /log to redirect to our website and any POSTs to /log to redirect to this service. I was trying to use the annotation cors-allow-methods but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: For that, I believe, you have to create two Ingress resources, one redirecting all methods other than POST to the website, and the other redirecting only POST.